# Have CLion suppress warnings/errors in external headers

Tags: compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, clion

I'm using CLion 2020.2 on GNU/Linux.

CLion compiles my project, or files within it, to display issues, errors, warnings and/or suggestions. And - it does so differently than the compilation CMakeLists.txt mandates. Some suggestions I can ignore, some I choose to handle; and this is all fine and good (well, sort of.)

My problem is that I also get suggestions or error indicators about headers which aren't mine - which are included from my project. A concrete example in my case: `/usr/local/cuda/includa/cuda.h`;  I see dozens of supposed errors in it, which I know are not really errors per se, since it's pretty standard and I didn't touch it. I also can't make changes to such files, for obvious reasons.

So, I just don't want to see errors and warnings from files outside my project. Can I limit CLion's error and warning reporting to achieve this?

<sub>Due disclosure: Have posted a very similar question to the official CLion forum.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

This is a long-known issue of Clion, afaik. Unfortunately, there isn't a direct way to suppress all the lib code from being inspected. But i can tell there is a way-around: changing the scope setting of each warning & error in the Inspections tab (see the attached pic). But as i said, you'll have to do it for every warning & error...

[image]

as shown above, by default it's "in all scopes" which of course includes the ones in library/system headers, change it to "project files".

Comment: Maybe a script could do this all at once on the config file?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dharman's comment, it reminds me and i did find something that's really helpful.

Look at the pic bellow, actually you can modify a bunch of options just by choosing the tree node on the left, and on the right you can set the "severity by scope" option for all the inspections under the node - just in one shot. i guess this is what you really want :)

[image]